# Assigning parsed JSON from SwiftyJSON API shows error

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I recently updated to [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29) from Objective-C, and it's really confusing while parsing JSON in a native way so while searching on Stack Overflow I found the SwiftyJSON API, and it's really cool. I am getting an error while assigning a parsed JSON value to a label. I have stored the result in an array, but while showing it on tableview it shows an error.

```
//Array where I store the parsed JSON
var categoryCount = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    getData()
}

func getData() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.artively.com/api/MobileApi/get_parent_category")
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                self.parseJSON(json)
            }
        }
}

func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
    for result in json["data"].arrayValue {
        print("The count are",result["product_count"].int!)
        self.categoryCount.append(result["product_count"].int!)
    }

    print("The category count are", categoryCount.count)
}
```

And finally when I execute this code the application crashes:

```
 cell.countLable.text =  "\(categoryCount[indexPath.row])"
      //Error appear in above code
```

This is the JSON result:

```
{
  "responsecode": "200",
  "responsemsg": "Successfull",
  "data": [
{
  "pk_category_id": 60,
  "category_name": "Collage",
  "category_logo": "http://www.artively.com//Upload/category_logo/28102015163738_collage_icon.png",
  "category_logo_selected": "http://www.artively.com//Upload/category_logo/28102015163738_collage_icon.png",
  "product_count": 10
},
{
  "pk_category_id": 65,
  "category_name": "Contemporary",
  "category_logo": "http://www.artively.com//Upload/category_logo/28102015163521_contempory_icon.png",
  "category_logo_selected": "http://www.artively.com//Upload/category_logo/28102015163521_contempory_icon.png",
  "product_count": 242
},
...So on
```

In the above response I have parsed the value of "product_count", storing it in an array and displaying it on a tableview cell, but the application crashes...

Comment: what does the crash say ?

Comment: Small suggestion. THe question title should be related to what question is about. Please edit the title of your question.

Comment: 1 - EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code = EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0X0).  2- Array index out of range.     This is what XCode display as an error

Comment: you are looking for an object which is not in the array.

Comment: @Mr.T Sir Can you elaborate Plz..

Comment: this line categoryCount[indexPath.row] will only work if the indexPath.row is less than the array count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After parsing you should call `self.tableView.reloadData()`. Then also make sure that you are implementing this method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.categoryCount.count
}
```

This will make sure that there are only as much rows as you have elements in your array and therefore `indexPath.row` will not exceed the array bounds.